# Issue provisioning bucket policy error: api error MalformedPolicy: Invalid policy syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

this is my terraform code. Im provisioning bucket s3 and a policy to attach it.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  
  policy = jsonencode({
     Version = "2012-10-17"
     Id      = "AllowGetObjects"
     Statement = [
        {
          Sid       = "AllowPublic"
          Effect    = "Allow"
          Principal = "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
          Actions    = ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"]
          Resource  = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/**"
        }
      ]
   })
}
```

this is the error stack

> api error MalformedPolicy:│   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy,
> │   on s3.tf line 32, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy":
> │   32: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {

Comment: cases like this I always try it in the AWS portal, it is easier to test/experiment there ...  the double asterisk `**` looks suspicious

Comment: Absolutely. You can validate your AWS policies via the console to be sure it works. I agree with @HelderSepulveda , the issue seems to be with your resource having the double asterisks.

Comment: @OlakunleAbiola you apply the permissions to an actual resource and check error stack or is there a simulator? policy generator doesnt throw resource error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error comes from your `principal` field, which should be a block that specifies that your value is an AWS `Service`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  
  policy = jsonencode({
     Version = "2012-10-17"
     Id      = "AllowGetObjects"
     Statement = [
        {
          Sid       = "AllowPublic"
          Effect    = "Allow"
          Principal = {
            Service = "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
          }
          Action    = ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"]
          Resource  = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*"
        }
      ]
   })
}
```

I have also removed the second `*`; as @Helder Sepulveda points out, it is redundant.

---

As @Dave Ankin pointed out, `Actions` needs to be `Action` — even when providing a list of actions.

Comment: should be "Action" not "Actions": `Error: putting S3 Bucket (test-react-router) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: , HostID: , api error MalformedPolicy: Unknown field Actions`

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my answer to reflect this fix.